# How can I create an alias name of a relational field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I need to create a model, to have backward compatibility with older field names.
This way,
I can develop modules that could read the "new" fields, but migrating the old ones is not necessary for this to work.
This works only for reading or presenting the fields, but not for writing them.

So I thought it would be good to create an alias for each field, and made this:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api


class backward_compatibility(models.Model):

    _description = 'Backward compatibility'
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    new_document_class_id = fields.Integer(
        compute='_comp_new_doc_class', string='Tipo')
    new_document_number = fields.Char(
        compute='_comp_new_doc_number', string='Folio')


    @api.multi
    def _comp_new_doc_class(self):
        for record in self:
            try:
                record.new_document_class_id = record.old_document_class_id
            except:
                pass

    @api.multi
    def _comp_new_doc_number(self):
        for record in self:
            try:
                record.new_document_number = record.old_document_number
            except:
                pass
```

This approach works for the Char field, but it doesn't for the Integer (Many2one).

What ideas do you have to make this work? Should I replicate the relationship in the new field?

Answer (score 0):

oldname: the previous name of this field, so that ORM can rename it automatically at migration

Try to use "oldname". I saw this in the core modules. Never used personally.

```
 _inherit = 'res.partner'
 _columns = {
        'barcode' : fields.char('Barcode', help="BarCode", oldname='ean13'),
  }
```

Also dummy fields are user to help with backward compatibility.

```
'pricelist_id': fields.dummy(string='Pricelist', relation='product.pricelist', type='many2one'),
```